How to find the infinite sum of a Poisson Random variable?
I have the following question

A company buys a policy to insure its revenue in the event of major snowstorms that shut down business. The policy pays nothing for the first such snowstorm of the year and 10,000 for each one thereafter, until the end of the year. The number of major snowstorms per year that shut down business is assumed to have a Poisson distribution with mean 1.5.
Calculate the expected amount paid to the company under this policy during a one-year period.

How do I go about finding the sum of the expectation of this Poisson random variable? I understand that I need to find the expected value of 10,000P(X=2) + 10,000P(X=3) +...+ 10,000P(X=n). Because they want the expectation and not just the probability, I can't simply use (1-P(X=0)-P(X=1) ).
I calculated the probability of P(X=0), P(X=1) and P(X=2) and I see that the probabilities approach 0. However, this isn't an arithmetic or a geometric series.
Some guidance would be appreciated.
